# CIP fails to load during vCenter installation - repeated errors

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, vsphere-client

I am trying to install VCSA 6.0 U3b. I have a Windows 7 64 bit machine running the latest version of Chrome. The CIP needs to be installed in order to run the setup. I've installed and I've explicitly allowed it when the pop came, but the setup simply fails to detect that the installation has already been done. I've tried numerous attempts, any pointers here would so much appreciated.

I get the following error repeatedly on Chrome.

[image]

Comment: I saw that too - but then we moved to 6.5, so that kinda/sorta fixed it :)

Comment: This is quite frustrating, I've imported the cert as instructed here as well https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2112076